# Excel Userform: How to ensure user data entry are uniform?

Tags: excel, vba

Im working on a excel template with a userform wherein clients receive a blank template then add employee data (name, username, birth date, department, job title, etc.). I want to make sure that the departments and job titles are uniform so that these columns can be filtered accurately. I've been researching on a combobox and listbox workaround. But im not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: Are facing any problem? If so, then post your codes where you facing problem?

Comment: @Harun24HR No i havent done any codes yet since im not sure how to proceed with this issue

Comment: It's in fact a very nice approach in your described situation as you can set `RowSource` properties to be named ranges!

Comment: @JvdV can you recommend any links where I can learn more perhaps get a sample code for this situation?

Comment: How many different titles and departments are possible? If less than 20, lists and comboboxes are perfectly fine. If more, you might want dependent lists (like Continent -> Country -> City).

Comment: @Sam I cant say for sure how many job titles and departments are possible, clients will determine this. Dependent lists may not apply if its more than 20 since the excel template will be blank.

Answer (score 1):

See below the most basic example I could think of right now. Maybe it helps you to figure out what you could do.

- First I have this piece of data:

[image]

- I have made these named ranges, and through the use of `INDEX` I made them dynamic. As you can see, mine is in Dutch, but the formula I used is `=Sheet1!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))` for all these named ranges:

[image]

- Third thing I did is create a simple userform, like below, and set the `RowSource` property of our 'mainstuff':

[image]

[image]

- We have to include some simple coding to add the named ranges to the `RowSource` property of our 'SubStuff', and upon changing the first combobox, the `RowSource` of the second one should change. Code should look something like this:

  ```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

  ComboBox2.RowSource = "Sub" & ComboBox1.Value

  End Sub
  ```
- When we play this code we get this:

[image]

- Or this, etc.:

[image]